# Is it possible to add a new string.xml that I created when the android application is running?

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, resources

Let -moi explain, I have a web service that can send me the translations I want to XML. I can create an .xml file exactly the same as the string.xml located in the resources of my project. My question is, is it possible to use my xml file instead of it while the program is running?

PS: I use Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot add anything while an app is being debugged. Actually, to correct myself; you can but your changes won't be reflected in the app you are debugging. You would need to stop the debugger on the emulator (or close the app if you are using an actual device to test), and rebuild the project to debug it again.

This needs to be done for both code and xml files.